# Why can't I pickle dataclass with defined __dict__ property?

Tags: python, pickle, python-dataclasses

I have simple dataclass which has `__dict__` defined, using `asdict`, but pickle refuses to serialize it

```py
import pickle
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int

    @property
    def __dict__(self):
        return asdict(self)

p = Point(10, 20)
assert p.__dict__ == {'x': 10, 'y': 20}
print(p.__dict__)

b = pickle.dumps(p)
p2 = pickle.loads(b)

print(p2)
```

outputs

```
{'x': 10, 'y': 20}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\others\pythonPlayground\data_class.py", line 18, in <module>
    p2 = pickle.loads(b)
  File "C:\Projects\others\pythonPlayground\data_class.py", line 11, in __dict__
    return asdict(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonPlayground\lib\dataclasses.py", line 1075, in asdict
    return _asdict_inner(obj, dict_factory)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pythonPlayground\lib\dataclasses.py", line 1082, in _asdict_inner
    value = _asdict_inner(getattr(obj, f.name), dict_factory)
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'x'
```

why is that and how to bypass this problem?
Or is there any other generic serialization library which can take almost anything, and serialize it to bytes, and it would work?

In the end I tried 2 different packages: `dill` and `cloudpickle` and `dill` works, while `cloudpickle` not.

Comment: Your `__dict__` is not an instance attribute; it's a *class* attribute that behaves somewhat like an instance attribute when accessed via an instance. `pick` is probably looking *specifically* for an instance attribute named `__dict__`.  Remember: dunder names are reserved for use by the implemeantion; you should not invent your own dunder names nor use existing ones in a way inconsistent with their defined behavior.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is this a bug on pickle side and should it be reported, that defining `__dict__` like this breaks the loading?

Comment: Not really. It's a bug on *your* end for trying to use `__dict__` in a way that you shouldn't. How `pickle` reacts to your error is undefined.

Comment: To be clear: do *not* define a property named `__dict__`.